# Aplicação em Cluster

Tags: c#

tenho que fazer uma aplicação C# em cluster, o que acontece é que eu não sei o que fazer. É uma aplicação simples. Alguém tem algum exemplo de aplicação deste tipo que me possa disponibilizar?

Answer (score 1):

Cara depende de como vai ser o seu cluster. Hoje eu tenho uma aplicação que roda num cluster de VM e dentro do cluster eu tenho uma VM com o IIS. Não tive que fazer nenhuma alteração na aplicação. Agora se o a tua a aplicação rodar em um Farm de IIS você vai ter que utilizar o SQL para armazenar as suas sessões.

Acho que esse artigo deve te dar uma ideia de como começar

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Abraço

Comment: É uma coisa bem simples para a faculdade, não precisa ser coisa muito complicada, sendo uma aplicação em Cluster como essa que você tem está mais que o suficiente.

Comment: Então você não tem muito com o que se preocupar não. Você pode escrever a tua aplicação normalmente